# pod getting wrong network

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

We are having dns resolution issues where when I look at the coredns pods I see the following:

```
coredns-576cbf47c7-7n2hq                              1/1     Running   0          11m    172.17.0.3       k8ctl-prod-02.hostname     <none>
coredns-576cbf47c7-jdrvb                              1/1     Running   0          59m    192.168.5.211    k8worker-prod-03.hostname   <none>
coredns-576cbf47c7-n9k8m                              1/1     Running   0          154d   192.168.4.38     k8worker-prod-02.hostname   <none>
```

I have 3 worker nodes and one of my worker nodes cannot get dns resolution because there is no dns pod running on it.

Questions I have are how can I get it to run on worker node (I have tried killing it and letting it respawn naturally but that seems to not work), I don't have any taints for it and I probably should but another question is why is it picking up the docker0 network when it should be picking up the kubernetes network on creation?

Thanks

Comment: do you check /etc/hosts?

Comment: Host file where?  In the pod or on the worker?  In either case there isn’t anything there and many other deployments don’t have this issue, it’s only coredns

Comment: in worker node you should define your master in /etc/hosts